# mysql php - latin1?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table, I made it in latin1 style and it is all that way.  How can I make a table that is all latin1 except one column, which i need to be able to accept chinese characters?

Also, Whats the best structure for a column with chinese characters?

Comment: use UTF-8 for every column...

Comment: I can't, for size reasons, all others must be latin1...

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table your_table
modify column
chinese_column varchar(255) collate utf8_general_ci; <-- or any relevant collate
```

details can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)